# Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to ArrayList<String> || Using Arraylist in JSP File

Tags: jsp, arraylist, type-mismatch

got a Method which returns an ArrayList with results from a Query:

```
public ArrayList<String> answerRequest(String table, String attribut) {

        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();

        try (Statement st = getMySQLConnection().createStatement();) {

            ResultSet daten = st.executeQuery("SELECT " + table + "." + attribut + " from " + table);

            while (daten.next()) {
                res.add(daten.getString(1));

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;

    }
```

This works fine, I call the method in my JSP File as Following:

```
<%
    ArrayList<String> res = new MySQLConnUtils().answerRequest("betreiber", "name");
for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
    out.println(res.get(i));
}
%>
```

I get this error and I dont get behind, because the function  "MySQLConnUtils().answerRequest" clearly Returns an array...

```
An error occurred at line: [17] in the jsp file: [/TESTJSP.jsp]
Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to ArrayList<String>
14: <body>
15: 
16:     <%
17:         ArrayList<String> res = new MySQLConnUtils().answerRequest("betreiber", "name");
18:     for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
19:         out.println(res.get(i));
20:     }
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you sure you are calling correct function ? Because this should work